# How can I make the find function in ocaml?

Tags: ocaml

I have to implement the `find` function of the module `List`:

```
val find : ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a
```

This is that I've got, but I don't get the type of the function, so I'm really lost:

```
let rec find p l= match l with
    []-> raise(Not_found)
    | h::t -> if h=p then p else find p t;;
```

This is the type of my function find:

```
val find : 'a -> 'a list -> 'a = <fun>
```

Comment: `p` should be a function that returns true when passed the item you're supposed to find, but it's not using it as a function. You're just comparing it directly against each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably you misunderstood what `find` was supposed to do.
What you wrote is trying to find `p` in a list, while `find` takes `p` to be a predicate, i.e., a property. You want to find an element `x` in the list satisfying `p`, i.e., such that `p x` is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have the following:

```
type account = { name : string; amount : int; }
let accounts = [{name = "Musterman"; amount = 10}; {name = "Musterfrau"; amount = -90}]
```

then you can find the account for "Musterman" by using:

```
List.find (fun a -> a.name = "Musterman") accounts
```

or accounts with a negative balance using

```
List.find (fun a -> a.amount < 0) accounts
```

Having the first argument of List.find be a function returning true when an list item is found makes List.find much more useful than a simple comparison to a know item.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list like:

```
let lst = [10; 1; 9; 2; ]
```

Then your find should take a function like:

```
find (fun x -> x = 10) lst
```

The above will find the node in the list which equals 10 if it exists.